# Baeldung: maven Non-resolvable parent

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying the Baeldung **Drools Spring Integration** described in [here](https://www.baeldung.com/drools-spring-integration). However, in the first step of resolving maven dependencies, I get the following error:

> [ERROR]   The project com.baeldung:spring-drools:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (spring-drools\pom.xml) has 1 error
>   [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.baeldung:spring-drools:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.baeldung:parent-modules:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 13 -> [Help 2]

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-drools</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-modules</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--spring integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <drools-version>7.0.0.Final</drools-version>
        <spring-framework.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Remove parent, and see.

Answer (score 3):

The following element is causing the problem

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-modules</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

This parent pom should be available in local maven repository. Please check your local maven repository.

Comment: Just to add to this, the parent should be coming from the root of the cloned repo, which is https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/pom.xml. So running `mvn clean install` from the root dir should make the artefact available.